# Possible bug with .SD lapply?

Tags: r, data.table

Using data.table version 1.8.8. Why does this work:

```
dat <- data.table(a=1:5,b=5:1)
sdat <- dat[,lapply(.SD,function(x) x*b)]
```

but this

```
dat <- data.table(a=1:5,b=5:1)
f <- function(x) x*b
sdat <- dat[,lapply(.SD,f)]
```

gives

```
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : object 'b' not found
```

Anything I'm missing?

Comment: I guess it's scoping, not a bug, and your second `f` doesn't find `b` because it looks in the environment in which it was defined, not inside `dat`, for objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't quite call this a bug - when you call `f`, `a` and `b` are being passed to it as a `vectors` called `x`. (More precisely, `.SD` is being passed)

So while `a` and `b` exist within `j`, the body of your function `f` is not evaluated within `j`.

To illustrate, see what happens when you run

```
with(dat, f(a))
```

I'd recommend just making `b` an argument of the function to avoid depending on name consistency down the road.

```
f = function(x,b) x * b
dat[,sapply(.SD, f, b=b)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should always pass the variables explictly if you use `lapply`:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- data.table(a=1:5, b=5:1)
f <- function(x, b) x*b
sdat <- dat[,lapply(.SD ,f, b=b)]
```

That avoids scoping issues.